# Python : 'Nonetype' object has no attribute when calling a method

Tags: python

Program 1 (main):

```
class SmartPlugMain(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, sfile):
        #declaration
        super().__init__(daemon=True, target=self.run)
        self.gui = GUI(self)
        self.start()
        self.gui.start()

    def run(self) :
        #perform some task

if __name__=='__main__':
    sfile = '/home/file'
    SmartPlugMain(sfile)
```

Program 2 :

```
class GUI(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, smartplug02):
        super().__init__(daemon=False, target=self.run)
        self.s_plug = smartplug02
        self.main_window = None

    def run(self):
        self.main_window = SmartPlugWindow(self)
        self.main_window.run()

    def display_message(self, message):
        self.main_window.display_message(message)   <- Nonetype error message

class SmartPlugWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self, sp_main):
        super().__init__()
        # declaration

    def run(self):
       # perform task

    def display_message(self, message)
      print(message)
```

Program 2 consist of classes.
When I run Program 1, the error message is `Nonetype` object has no attribute `display_message`. It is referring to `self.main_window.display_message(message)`

Comment: This is happening because, at the time you call `self.main_window.display_message(message)`, `self.main_window` has the value `None`. You are not calling `run()` which is where it gets a value, so it is still `None` because that is what the constructor set it to.

Comment: Thanks. I need to send a  value to SmartPlugWindow.display_message from Program 1- run().  I did : self.gui.display_message()  then it will call self.main_window.display_message. Any advice how to solve the error.